# What to do with questions that do not get any answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

At the moment there are 391 questions without answers, see https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=mostvotes&filters=noanswers

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers one could create a bounty to get more awareness.

However, what is the opinion regarding closing questions if they are inactive for longer than three months?

**December 20, 2019**

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops

[image]

**December 22, 2019**

[image]

**December 23, 2019**

[image]

**December 25, 2019**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@030 thank you that you take care of that to develop our site towards successful end of the Beta status.

It seems to me that asking authors of the questions whether they've found an answer in the meantime is a good approach! In terms of Beta state, I think getting more answers to get the 2.5 answers/question will be more tough though.